# Postgres replication size send during the streaming replication progress

Tags: postgresql, replication

I would like to ask a quest about postgresql-12 streaming replication. I just want to know the size of file/data/packet sent out trough the replication, with standard configuration of 16MB per segments size. Its going send out exactly 16MB per transaction or less? any tools to find it out other than tcpdump or wireshark. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a WAL record is written to the WAL buffers shared memory area, it will be streamed to the standby immediately. WAL records have variable size. WAL can be streamed to the standby even before the transaction ends.

Comment: You are right. I did iftop and can see the network usage. Thank you.